# Correctly grouping this query to get minimum value ONLY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table cars:

```
id  serial  size    batch
--------------------------
1   x99     Large    NULL
2   x99     Small    Q
3   x99     Med     NULL
4   x99     Large    K
```

Is joined twice with table codeassignment:

```
Id  serial  size    batch   code    precedence
-----------------------------------------------
1   x99     Large   NULL    5000    1
2   x99     NULL      K     3000    2
3   x99     NULL      Q     2000    3
4   x99     NULL    NULL    500     4
```

using the following:

```
select 
    c.*, 
    coalesce(ca1.code, ca2.code) as code, 
    min(coalesce(ca1.precedence, ca2.precedence)) as precedence
from
    cars c 
left join
    codeassignment ca1 on ca1.serial = c.serial 
                       and (ca1.size = c.size or ca1.batch = c.batch) 
left join
    codeassignment ca2 on ca2.serial = c.serial 
                       and ca1.size is null and ca2.size is null 
                       and ca1.batch is null and ca2.batch is null
group by 
    c.id, c.serial, c.size, c.batch, ca1.code, ca2.code
```

But it results in matches for 'Large' and batch 'K' coming up twice:

```
id  serial  size    batch   code    precedence
----------------------------------------------
1   x99     Large   A       5000    1
2   x99     Small   Q       2000    3
3   x99     Med     P       500     4
4   x99     Large   K       3000    2
4   x99     Large   K       5000    1
```

I want to select all the above rows but for the last two, only the one with the minimum precedence (that's why I'm trying `min(precedence)`) but I think the group by is all wrong to do this properly. So basically where `serial`, `size` and `batch` are the same there should only be the one row.

Here's a fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47700d67170a7beb39bfc523ffdfbcfc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the belated answer, but I still had this open. Going to finish it anwyway as an alternative.

If I understand the goal correctly, you want to match on serial number, size if filled and batch if filled, where precedence is leading, no matter if the fields being filled are a "stronger" match?

Then a single join could suffice:

```
select c.Serial, c.Size,c.Batch, min(isnull(ca.Precedence,0)) Precedence
from cars c
left join codeassignment ca on ca.serial = c.serial and (ca.size is null or ca.size=c.size) and (ca.batch is null or ca.batch=c.batch)
group by c.Serial,c.Size,c.Batch
```

[image: Results]

That's just to show the single join and not needing ca1 and ca2 (unless I am missing some requirement)

Having that as a base, another way to match on a minimum or other aggregate, is using window functions instead of group by. I have a slight preference for those (in combination with a cte, since you can't use a window function as a criterium directly)

```
with q as(
select c.*, ca.Code, ca.Precedence, row_number() over (partition by c.Serial, c.Size, c.Batch order by Precedence) rnr
from cars c
left join codeassignment ca on ca.serial = c.serial and (ca.size is null or ca.size=c.size) and (ca.batch is null or ca.batch=c.batch)
)
select Serial, Size, Batch, Precedence, Code
from q
where rnr = 1
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The double join was from a solution to an issue I had yesterday. At the time, I didn't have the precedence column in, it was only later that some other conditions came up it was introduced. I might be able to use this answer to make my queries much more succinct and I'll investigate now.

Comment: Took a little bit of tinkering because I had an extra column from another joined table to incorporate but I got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are grouping by "too many things" in your query, so you end up with discrete rows where you don't want them. One way to fix this is to break your query into two stages, one to get the minimum precedence per id, serial, size and batch, and then to get the missing data. Something like this:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        c.id, 
        c.serial, 
        c.size, 
        c.batch, 
        MIN(ISNULL(ca1.precedence, ca2.precedence)) AS precedence
    FROM 
        cars c 
        LEFT JOIN codeassignment ca1
            ON ca1.serial = c.serial AND (ca1.size = c.size OR ca1.batch = c.batch) 
        LEFT JOIN codeassignment ca2 ON ca2.serial = c.serial AND ca1.size is null and ca2.size is null and ca1.batch is null and ca2.batch is null
     GROUP BY 
        c.id, 
        c.serial, 
        c.size, 
        c.batch)
SELECT
    x.*,
    ISNULL(ca1.code, ca2.code) AS code
FROM
    x
    INNER JOIN cars c ON c.id = x.id AND c.serial = x.serial AND c.size = x.size AND c.batch = x.batch
    LEFT JOIN codeassignment ca1
     ON ca1.serial = c.serial and (ca1.size = c.size or ca1.batch = c.batch) AND ca1.precedence = x.precedence
    LEFT JOIN codeassignment ca2
     ON ca2.serial = c.serial and
     ca1.size is null and ca2.size is null and ca1.batch is null and ca2.batch is null AND ca2.precedence = x.precedence;
```

I couldn't get the fiddle to work with this for some reason, but I can run this locally on SQL Server 2019 to get:

```
id  serial  size    batch   precedence  code
1   x99     Large   A       1           5000
2   x99     Small   Q       3           2000
3   x99     Med     P       4           500
4   x99     Large   K       1           5000
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine on the fiddle for me! Awesome, thank you. I really need some practice with CTEs they seem to be an answer for more than half of my SQL problems.